# Include Java3d in Netbeans dist

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, jar, java-3d

I have a Java project in Netbeans, which uses Java3d. When I distribute the jar file, it doesn't work. I tried various ways to add the files vecmath.jar, j3dutils.jar, j3dcore.jar, but they seem to be ignored. I tried to run the resulting jar on another PC with Windows XP, and I asked a friend to try it on Mac, and it didn't launch.

What I tried so far and didn't work (based on answers on the Internet, some maybe don't make sense, but I tried everything I could find):

- check enable native packaging actions in project menu
- distribute the dist folder, including a folder named lib generated by Netbeans, with the three Java3d jars
- right click the project, Properties->Libraries, and add there the Java3d jars
- right click the Libraries folder under the project, and add jar/folder
- include a folder with the jars in the src folder
- create a library with "Add Library..." from "Project Properties", in the "Global Libraries" folder, and added it to the project.
  Nothing worked.

If I make a Windows installer with "Package as", the installation works on Windows XP (although if I doubleclick the jar, is not launched). How can I make an installer for Mac?

To resume, the questions are:

- How can I distribute the Java3d jar files so that it works on other computers?
- In particular, I am interested for Mac

**Update**

Here is the error I get when running the jar file on Windows XP:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl-chk in java.library.path
```

I added the dll files, and it works. I have to see how I make it work on Mac.

Comment: Just a side note: Java3D comes with some *native* libraries. On Windows, these are some DLL files, usually installed in the `Program Files/Java/Java3D.../` subdirectory. If you do *not* have these native libraries for *Mac*, then any package that you create on Windows will not work on Mac. A first try would be to get these files (probably `.dylib` files) from a Mac user who has installed Java3D, and then somehow try to include them in the package. (This *might* already be done when you enable "native packaging", but the files must be *present* in the first place...)

Comment: Use the latest version of Java 3D instead of going on using absolutely obsolete craps that don't support latest versions of OS X anyway. You're wasting your time. Good luck: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb